# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I created this query in MySQL for a dental practice

`SELECT Paz.Nome, Paz.Cognome
FROM Paziente AS Paz, Visita AS Vis
WHERE Vis.Paziente=Paz.CF AND MAX(Vis.Parcella)=Vis.Parcella`

But not work for the error 1111. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've specified the second table in a join, the max statement needs to be in the form of a subquery:

```
SELECT 
Paz.Nome, 
Paz.Cognome 
FROM Paziente AS Paz
LEFT JOIN Visita AS Vis  ON Vis.Paziente=Paz.CF
WHERE  (SELECT MAX(Parcella) FROM Visita)=Vis.Parcella;
```

Comment: Thank you, is perfect! I can't vote because my reputation is inferior of 15

Comment: Thanks @Fab95s happy to have helped! Can still select this as the correct answer?